# What is the greatest number of reviews resulting in a "not out" decision for one player in a Test Match innings?

Tags: cricket, trivia

During the first test of England's 2016 tour of Bangladesh, Moeen Ali was given not out in five LBW reviews (3 successfully overturned, 2 incorrect reviews by Bangladesh) in the first innings of the match.

Has anyone survived more player reviews (as opposed to umpire reviews), either the same type or different, in an innings during a test match?

Comment: I'm not getting this : Has anyone survived more player reviews (as opposed to umpire reviews) because i think those 3 overturned reviews were umpire reviews. Am i getting this question wrong?

Comment: @RamchandraGiri an umpire review is when an umpire is not sure on a decision, for example a runout, and refers to the 3rd umpire. Whereas a player review is when an umpire makes a decision and the relevant player(s) choose to challenge the decision, eg LBW. In the case of this question, all of the decisions were LBW. Those overturned were where the umpire gave Moeen Ali Out, and he challenged the call, and was successful in getting it changed to Not Out in all three cases.

Answer (score 1):

Article from [FOX SPORTS](https://www.foxsports.com.au/cricket/cricket-video-england-batsman-moeen-ali-rides-his-luck-to-survive-three-reviews-in-an-over/news-story/144dae58192570be76679d1d2c76eab3) mention:

> These three successful reviews happened in the space of six deliveries, from the same bowler to the same batsman.
>
> It’s been reported no player has successfully appealed as many “out” decisions in a Test innings previously, let alone in the space of an over.
>
> Ali would survive a further two DRS appeals throughout his innings, both reviewed by Bangladesh after the batsman had been given not out.

So it is clear that 5 reviews against **Moeen Ali** is the highest against a player in an innings during a test match until now. So **no player has survived more player reviews**.

And from same article:

> when Stuart Broad successfully appealed the umpire’s decision against him at the start of day two, it set a new record (nine) for most reviews used in a Test innings.

Comment: +1 for the article find, however I would disagree with your statement that *it is clear that 5 reviews against Moeen Ali is the highest*. I say this because a team's available review count gets topped-up to 2 every 80 overs. So, for example, another batsmen could have had 2 reviews successfully overturned, but the bowling side *could* have unsuccessfully reviewed against that batsman 4 times, giving a total of 6 "survived" reviews. I'm not saying you are wrong, Moeen most probably has survived the most, but it is not definite.